# GVIM: How can I run a command on a large number of buffers without needing user input?

Tags: vim, buffer

I need to make a series of changes to a large number of files. I found that `:bufdo` allows me to make those changes but after operating on a number of buffers it pauses until the user presses a button. How can I just have it run through all the files without pausing?

Comment: What action do you want to perform? What is the message asking for you to press a button? How many buffers do you want to act on? The "pause" happens after how many buffers?

Comment: I'm doing a search and replace. It happens after 15-20 buffers are changed. The message is either --More-- or --More-- SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q:quit

Comment: I usually use `silent! argdo blablabla` after making sure my command works as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the *more prompt*, you can press `G` to let all further output proceed without another interruption.

If you do not wany *any* prompt, you can temporarily `:set nomore` (undo with `:set more`).

Alternatively, you can try my [ArgsAndMore plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4152), it defines `:Bufdo`, `:Windo`, etc. commands that do this and automatically return to the original buffer.